# Sql Server CE 4 Insert Default Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce-4

Using Sql Server CE 4 I have created the follow table.

`create table abc(id int identity(1,1) primary key)`

If I try and insert a row to generate a new identity using the following:

`insert into abc default values`

I get an error stating there is an issue near the default word.

How can I do this using Sql Server CE 4 or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [abcd] (
  [id] int NOT NULL  IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
, [payload] bit NULL
);
GO
INSERT INTO abcd (payload) VALUES (0);
GO
```

Or assing the INT value yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
insert into abc (id) values (default)
```

Comment: Get the error: `the column cannot be modified. [ Column name = id ]`

Comment: umh At least in SQL Server I can't test now in CE this: INSERT t1 DEFAULT VALUES Quit "table"